# xeditable form need to be enabled Edit mode by default

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

I'm using [xeditable](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-table) angular directive.Could you tell me how to enable the edit mode by default ? I mean without clicking the `Edit` button.Thanks in advance.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/78/)

I don't need the `Edit` button as shown below.

```
 <!-- buttons -->
    <div class="btn-edit">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-show="!tableform.$visible" ng-click="tableform.$show()">
        edit
      </button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/9123/

added `ng-init="tableform.$show()"` on form

**2nd Solution :**

> shown bool - Whether form initially rendered in shown state.

```
<form editable-form name="tableform" shown="true">
```

Comment: so I am presuming you need the editable form up on form load. If that's not the case please comment

Comment: Any how it's not working on my app.Do you have any guess ?

Comment: in your app? it has the same structure and tag names right?

Comment: yes,form name is the same.The only difference is where it's loading inside the popup.Is that a problem ?

Comment: does your popup has separate controller?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support :)